# Backup Exec 11D and Thecus N5200 Pro

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-attached-storage, backup-restoration, backupexec, tape

I have a Thecus N5200 Pro integrated into my Windows 2003 AD network. My current backup solution involves Backup Exec 11D but this requires a running service for windows boxes or a similar daemon for linux machines. The N5200 runs a custom linux kernel but as of yet I am unable to add it to my backups through Backup Exec.

Does anyone know of a method of backing up directly from the N5200 to Backup Exec without moving the data to an intermediary for archiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I didn't get any answers for this one and thus far I have not been able to find any. What I have decided to do instead was migrate from Backup Exec to ntbackup. This allows me to backup from / to any device connected to the network.

If in the future someone discovers a Thecus module or linux daemon then please feel free to post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Backup Exec 2010 to do just this (With this same NAS).  It's easy to point to the shares off of it once you enable "Enable Selection of User Shares" under ctrl-o (Options) -> "Network and Security".

Then you can just pick what you want from the NAS as if it were a disk on a server with the agent loaded on it.

Comment: For what it's worth, that is also possible with v12.5